# Make a type Double behave responsively to Integer and Doubly typed assignments

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
public class doubles() {
    private Double a;

    public Double getA(){
        return this.a 
    }
    public void setA(Double a){
      this.a = a
    }
}
```

I want the variable 'a' to retain the properties of an integer when I do for instance

```
**setA(13)**
```

i.e a=13 and not a=13.0

Still I want variable 'a' to have the properties of a Double when I for instance

```
**setA(13.32)**
```

i.e a=13.32

Comment: This is called "Method Overloading" .I already answered this question a few days back look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53585110/how-do-i-incorporate-method-overloading-to-call-different-parameter-types-for-on/53585147#53585147

Comment: thanks @M.Dan, I've looked at the link. However, the answer provided does not suit my scenario since I cannot declare the variable 'a' with different types; as in private Double a and private Integer a

Comment: take a look at code below @mikaelovi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the small code for what you need. Please, bare in mind that I strongly advice not to follow this principle.

```
public class Example {

    private Number a;

    public Number getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(Double a) {
        if (a % 1 == 0) {
            this.a = a.intValue();
        } else {
            this.a = a;
        }
    }

    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double integerNumber = 6;

        Example example = new Example();
        example.setA(integerNumber);
        System.out.println(example.getA());
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for your response but it still outputs 5.0. Would want it to output 5 in this case and then 5.3 if 5.3 was given

Comment: Changes applied, take a look! @mikaelovi

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to using the base class **Number** proposed in the other answer, one can use **BigDecimal**: a class which stores the precision / decimal places. Hence 3.10 * 2.00 = 6.2000.

```
   new BigDecimal("3.10").multiply(new BigDecimal("2.00"))
```

Disadvantage: the awkward verbosity.

Advantage: precision (called scale) and does not have the approximation errors of floating point: 3.1 = 3.100 = actually 3.099999871...

Comment: many thanks for your approach, but I'll go with the accepted answer.